# Facebook Share showing _escaped_fragment_ URL instead of hash version

Tags: ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I've created a single-page app. All deep links are in the form of mysite.com/#!/entry_title. This allows Google (and Facebook) to check an alternate URL for the content of that page.

I've setup a server-side check to determine if Google or Facebook is looking for the HTML snapshot of this page. If so, it sends a different header containing the necessary Facebook og meta tags.

Here's the problem. If I paste one of my URLs (mysite.com/#!/entry_title) into my status box the URL that gets displayed is the HTML snapshot URL (mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_/entry_title).

The og:url meta tag on the HTML snapshot page is set to mysite.com/#!/entry_title.

How can I make the Sharer display the mysite.com/#!/entry_title version of the URL instead of the HTML snapshot version?

Thanks in advance!

- Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out and thought I'd post the answer for others.

The trick is to setup a redirect for Google/Facebook to go to a prettier URL. So any URL in the form of

```
mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_/entry_title
```

gets redirected to something prettier like

```
mysite.com/view/entry_title
```

When someone shares one of my dynamic URLs, Facebook requests the _escaped_fragment_ version of the page, and gets redirected to my prettier URL (mysite.com/view/entry_title), which is what gets shown in the Facebook post.

To make sure people always share my dynamic URL I've setup a javascript redirect on the mysite.com/view/entry_title pages to redirect back to the mysite.com/#!/entry_title pages.

While this doesn't show the dynamic URL in the Facebook Share, it shows a prettier URL than the _escaped_fragment_ version and forces people back to the dynamic URL that I want people to share.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. I still have no solution. But I think your solution is too complex.