# How to add params before hash in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, facebook, ionic2

I need my server to receive params to be able to do some better sharing for social platforms like facebook.

So for example when a user goes to a page at `mysite.com` for item 1001, I want it to prepend a param before the # `mysite.com?item=1001/#/`.

This is so that if a user copies that url and shares it, the facebook bot's request for the page will include `?item=1001` in its request so I can redirect the page to our server to serve the meta page with the relevant information.

Any information after the # doesn't get sent to the server because the browser understands that it is only for the client to use.

**Is it possible in Ionic to prepend query params to the url while doing normal ionic page navigation?** `mysite.com?item=1001/#/`

Comment: Is this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653183/facebook-share-showing-escaped-fragment-url-instead-of-hash-version?rq=1) answers your question ?

Comment: No, I ended up just accessing the window directly instead of making use of the ionic routing libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using `window` to do this instead of making use of the ionic routing libraries.

```
window.history.replaceState( 
   {} , 
   "Title",
   `${window.location.origin}?item=${this.item_id}/${window.location.hash}`
);
```

Which changes the url to `mysite.com?item=1001/#/nav/n4/other_stuff` as desired.  This link can then be copied and shared and the backend will be aware of the content that it needs to generate if it is a bot